# How can I make excel macro run on cells in active row?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having trouble with a macro I'm trying to make. I have a spreadsheet and I'm concerned with columns A, Q, R, S, and T. First I select a row in column Q as my initial activecell for the macro. I make column Q into 0. Then I put a sum formula in column A that Sums R,S, and T for the row I'm in. 
Then I copy and paste values on the column A cell so that the sum is a value. I make column T = Column A. Then I put 0s in columns R and S.

The below is the inital macro made using record macro, but it only applies to the row that I recorded the macro on. I want the macro to be so that when I do Ctrl-g on any row, it will run for that row.

```
Sub Cashflow()
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+g
'
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "0"
    Range("A74").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[17]:RC[19])"
    Range("A74").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A74").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("T74").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-19]"
    Range("R74").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "0"
    Range("S74").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "0"
    Range("T74").Select
End Sub
```

This is what I did to try to fix it, but it doesn't work:

```
 Sub Cashflow()
    '
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+g
    '
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "0"
        Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 1)).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[17]:RC[19])"
        Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 1)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 1)).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 20)).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-19]"
        Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 18)).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "0"
        Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 19))
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "0"
        Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 20)).Select
    End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

1. Avoid `.Select` And `.Activate`. it adds actions and slows the code.  Just do what you want with the range.
2. Instead of using the clipboard just assign the values directly to the cell.
3. `With` blocks help cut down the amount of repetitive typing.
4. Get in the habit now of declaring all parent sheets to every range object.

Use this:

```
Sub Cashflow()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Selection
If rng.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
rng = 0
With rng.Parent
    With Cells(rng.Row, 1)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[17]:RC[19])"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    .Cells(rng.Row, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-19]"
    .Range(.Cells(rng.Row, 18), .Cells(rng.Row, 19)).Value = 0
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually just figured out how to fix my problem, but your code is much shorter and cleaner.      *edit* Wait actually the above code doesn't seem to get the correct sum or zero out the middle columns, but thanks anyways!